# Not getting nested property value

Tags: javascript, nested-object

I have a function to convert units to my native language. My function -

```js
const toCorrectUnitLanguage = (unit, langLocale = 'en') => {
  const savedUnits = {
    sec: { en: 'Sec', bn: 'সেকেন্ড' },
    min: { en: 'Min', bn: 'মিনিট' },
    hour: { en: 'Hour', bn: 'ঘন্টা' },
  }
  if (savedUnits[unit.toLowerCase()]) {
    return savedUnits[unit.toLowerCase()][langLocale];
  }
  return unit;
}

console.log(toCorrectUnitLanguage('sec'))
console.log(toCorrectUnitLanguage('sec', 'en'))
console.log(toCorrectUnitLanguage('sec', 'bn'))
```

I am getting the correct object when I am logging `savedUnits[unit.toLowerCase()]`.
I am also getting the value I want if I hard code `savedUnits[unit.toLowerCase()]["en"]`

But I am getting `undefined` when I am returning  `savedUnits[unit.toLowerCase()][langLocale]`

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
Calling the function like this -

```
toCorrectUnitLanguage('sec',langLocale)
```

My node version is `13.14.0`. Could that be an issue?

**Edit 2:**
My `console.log`

```
if (savedUnits[unit.toLowerCase()]) {
  console.log(savedUnits[unit.toLowerCase()]); //{en: 'Sec', bn: 'সেকেন্ড'}
  console.log(savedUnits[unit.toLowerCase()][langLocale]); //undefined
  return savedUnits[`${unit.toLowerCase()}`][langLocale];
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce: see the snippet I edited into your question

Comment: Updated the question with calling and node version

Comment: runs fine on my end

Comment: @HimuraDaBattosuai The value of `langLocale` is probably not `'en'`, `'bn'`, or `undefined` when you are calling the function. Put `console.log(langLocale)` before `toCorrectUnitLanguage('sec',langLocale)` and you will see. If `langLocale` is `null` it will not use the default value. Next time please provide a reproducible example, chances are you will find the issue when trying to reproduce the problem.